Pyaudio symbol not found in flat namespace error
I am trying to follow this tutorial here and when after installing portaudio, and going to run the code, I run into this error meassge:
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/adelaide/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyaudio/init.py", line 111, in 
import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/adelaide/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'
I am running on an M3 Pro Max, seems that pyaduio and portaudio possibly encounter issues with Apple Silicon?
This thread seems to be having the same issue but no one was able to help. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling every package on the tutorial, homebrew, and even going to check that they are all installed in the proper env. I am using conda if that helps. I have tried a plethora of other forced installs with tags that I have found on previous threads but nothing seems to work.
